# Running a program while the computer is turned off

Tags: c#, twitter, bots

I made a program. It tweets automatically every hour. What can I do to make it work when the computer is off. For example, there is an account called @everycolorbot, what is the working logic of this account?

Comment: As far as I know, when the computer is off it can't run programs. Running programs when the computer is off seems like an XY problem--maybe put it on [glitch](http://glitch.com/) or some other cloud host instead. I host my twitter bot on heroku and it runs a daily [worker task](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

Comment: As for everycolorbot, just [look at the source](https://github.com/vogon/everycolor). It runs on heroku.

Comment: I wrote the program in c#. Which cloud host should I use?

Comment: @Myrias Whichever one you want that suits your needs. Asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow. Do some research, try some options, see what does and does not work for you.

Comment: btw; this looks to be using a hot loop that is *continually* checking for a time conditional that is *very rarely* satisfied; you should really really look into `await Task.Delay(...)`, for example `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60))` - *much* more efficient; note that this won't help you running anything while the computer is off, of course; for that, you'll need to run it on *someone else's* computer, which might need it to be written in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Azure Functions, where you only pay for compute time:

1. Create a new [Functions project](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). Either in Visual Studio or On-Line. My preference is VS because I can keep the code in source control. You might need to open Visual Studio Installer and install Azure tools - either way, check out the docs at the Azure Functions link that I just posted here to make sure you're working with the latest info.
2. While creating the Functions project, choose a [Timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp).
3. Take the defaults and it will create a new function project for you:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TweetMyStuff
{
    public static class MyTweetBot
    {
        [FunctionName("MyTweetBot")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            // your tweet logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I set the chron setting on the `TimerTrigger` parameter attribute to `"0 * * * *"` This will start the function every hour on the hour. Azure has [chron expression syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions), which matches the Linux syntax (so you can find more information by a web search).

4. Finally, deploy and monitor - you can visit the [QuickStart for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) to help you get started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but I could not understand. Where do I type keys and tokens? I have already made a console program with tweetinvi. Can't I publish it?

Comment: I add my code in my question

Comment: @Myrias you *really really* don't want to publish the code shown in the question to run on a cloud server where you're paying for compute time - you have a hot loop, so it is just *burning* compute; the approach shown here is a good way of running something in a *scheduled* way, very efficiently